# How do you adjust the dock bounce animation in OSX?

Tags: macos, dock

I'd like to adjust the animation for bouncing dock icons in OSX. (I'm running Yosemete 10.10.3) I've already found [this article](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/how-to-permanently-stop-dock-icons-from-bouncing/) showing how to completely disable the bounce, but I want more control than simply ON/OFF. Is there a way to adjust the animation? Specifically, I want to change:

- number of bounces before it stops

  - Right now, it just bounces forever, until you switch over to that application and deal with whatever it's nagging you about.
- bounce height
- bounce frequency
- bounce speed

Can these things be changed, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think that you can change these aspects of the dock behaviour. In the several years of using and tweaking my laptop with defaults.write commands I did not come across such a customisation. Can't provide hard proof though.

Comment: I believe "number of bounces" can be controlled by the code/developer of the application that is triggering the notification, but the rest of your requested settings are not configurable.

Comment: Very annoying feature. I wish no more bouncing in Apple OSX and replaced with notification number, and please sit there silently!